# How to register spring 5 application to eureka client

Tags: spring, client, netflix-eureka, discovery

Thank you for your reply.
i don't know what registers spring(5) application as eureka client.
my application is just read data.
i found that example code before, but i can't apply some code.
and i didn't know what how to execute eureka client code when start my application.

found code

```
DiscoveryManager.getInstance().initComponent(new MyDataCenterInstanceConfig(), new DefaultEurekaClientConfig());

  String vipAddress = "MY-SERVICE";

    InstanceInfo nextServerInfo = null;
    try {
        nextServerInfo = DiscoveryManager.getInstance()
                .getEurekaClient()
                .getNextServerFromEureka(vipAddress, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot get an instance of example service to talk to from eureka");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("Found an instance of example service to talk to from eureka: "
            + nextServerInfo.getVIPAddress() + ":" + nextServerInfo.getPort());

    System.out.println("healthCheckUrl: " + nextServerInfo.getHealthCheckUrl());
    System.out.println("override: " + nextServerInfo.getOverriddenStatus());

    System.out.println("Server Host Name "+ nextServerInfo.getHostName() + " at port " + nextServerInfo.getPort() );
```

i thought my application executes url "/" in MainController when start.
so, i just that code writes in "/" GetMapping method of MainController.
but i got a error this.
cannot access javax.inject.Provider class file for javax.inject.Provider not found.

how to make code for registers as eureka client and how to use that code...
please help junior! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try use configuration files?
example: application.properties or yml?

Eureka Server:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 9091
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 3000
    enableSelfPreservation: false
```

Microservices Client:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 9091
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.port}/eureka/
  server:
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 3000
```

Comment: thank you i am spring beginner so i didn't know what can solve way...thanks. anyway i solved problem myself use resttemplate.
and my next step is properties file changes yml file.
thank you very much !!! good luck @Diego Mauricio